# Potential Java/arm64 error when loading the xlsx package in R?

Tags: java, r, installation, arm64, rjava

I am having trouble loading the xlsx package on R (via RStudio). The error message I get when I try to call the package is as below.

```
> library(xlsx)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

From what I can understand this seems to be a rJava issue and not a problem with library(xlsx) per se. I can confirm that the xlsx package is installed on my computer, it just can't be loaded. I'm using a MacBook running arm64, and I'm running the arm64 version of both R and Rstudio.

I tried to replace my existing version of Java with the arm64 version of the JRE (obtained from this link: https://www.java.com/en/download/). According to terminal, `java -version` now returns

```
java version "1.8.0_381"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_381-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.381-b09, mixed mode)
```

However now when I try to run the xlsx package on R I get the following fatal error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000002880bf2cc, pid=1308, tid=0x0000000000000103
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_381) (build 1.8.0_381-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.381-b09 mixed mode bsd-aarch64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~StubRoutines::jshort_disjoint_arraycopy
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Looks like I've somehow managed to make things worse. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You may wish to look at the [openxlsx](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=openxlsx) package which provides similar functonality without any Java dependency. It's based on C++ and Rcpp.

Comment: I haven't tried recent versions for quite some time, but sometimes it's easiest to build stuff from the sources: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/ https://www.owsiak.org/r4-0-with-java-14-inside-macos-10-15-4/